# How to optimize this JavaScript code snippet?

Tags: javascript, optimization

The following piece of code is ran on app launch. The params come in on the URL, and products will contain a list of product codes such as electronics|J7|F4|T4. Electronics is the only code that doesn't need to be mapped. Others need to be mapped to text values.

We need to create a product sequence from the above product codes so that we get [electronics, apparel, shoes, groceries].

Any simple ways to optimize the code to make it less verbose?

```
var products = params.products;
var productCodes = policyType.split('|');
var productArray = [];
productCodes.forEach(function(productCode) {
    if(productCode === constants.ELECTRONICS) {
        productArray.push(productCode);
    } else {
        productArray.push(maps.PRODUCT_BY_CODE[productCode]);
    }
})
productSequenceManager.setProductSequence(productArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, I would do something like this:

```
var productArray = policyType
  .split('|')
  .map(function(productCode) {
    return productCode === constants.ELECTRONICS ? 
      productCode : 
      maps.PRODUCT_BY_CODE[productCode];
  });
productSequenceManager.setProductSequence(productArray);
```